# How to select a constant according to a generic in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, constants

I'm trying to work on a math library that has constants and functions. What I need to do to bind a value to a trait that uses generics?

The functions in my Rust 1.30.0 project that employs generics as parameters and I need the constants to match the same type of `T` so I can operate with them in a function (here I am also using the num crate):

```
use num_traits as ntraits; // 0.2.6
use std::{f32, f64};

pub trait consts<T> {
    const INGA: T;
}

impl<T> consts<f32> for T {
    const INGA: f32 = f32::consts::FRAC_2_SQRT_PI;
}

impl<T> consts<f64> for T {
    const INGA: f64 = f64::consts::FRAC_2_SQRT_PI;
}

pub struct CMPS<T> {
    pub a: T,
    pub b: T,
}

pub type CMPS32 = CMPS<f32>;
pub type CMPS64 = CMPS<f64>;

impl<T: Clone + ntraits::Float + ntraits::FromPrimitive> CMPS<T> {

    pub fn cerf(a: T, b: T) -> CMPS<T> {
        let pr: T = consts::INGA;
        let rtr = a;
        let rti = b;
        CMPS { a: rtr, b: rti }
    }
}
```

But when I try to perform this binding, expecting `pr` to be the same type as `T` and match the value of `INGA` as this:

```
let pr: T = consts::INGA;
```

It only outputs errors like:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `_: consts<T>`
  --> src/lib.rs:27:21
   |
27 |         let pr: T = consts::INGA;
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: required by `consts::INGA`
  --> src/lib.rs:5:5
   |
5  |     const INGA: T;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: It's pretty difficult to answer this because it's incomplete, and there is so much wrong with your syntax. It's very difficult to understand what you are _trying_ to do. I am guessing you didn't intend `impl<T> consts<f32> for T`, which means "implement the trait `consts<f32>` for _every possible_ type that could exist".

Comment: At a guess, you may have intended: `impl consts<f32> for f32` and `impl consts<f64> for f64`?

Comment: Please consider providing a [mcve]. As it stands, I can't just copy your code to get the same error. For example, where is the line `let pr: T = consts::INGA;`? Is it in `main`? Is it in a function with a bound `T` type variable?

Comment: Do you think you could edit your question so that someone can copy the code and get the same error?

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, and fields; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants. Use `Consts` instead, please.

Answer (score 0):

I got it by adding `+ consts<T>` in the `CMPS` implementation and changing `let pr: T = consts::INGA;` to `let pr = T::INGA` resulting in the following:

```
impl<T: Clone + ntraits::Float + ntraits::FromPrimitive + consts<T>> CMPS<T> {
    pub fn cerf(a: T, b: T) -> CMPS<T> {
        let pr = T::INGA;
        CMPS { a: rtr, b: rti }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this will not work, because with these trait bounds `fn cerf(...` will not be present for CMPS32 and CMPS64

Comment: Before you did this, how would you have expected the compiler to know that *for **any** type `T`*, the trait was implemented for it?